# Check bit flags for included decimal number

Tags: php, bitmap

I need to check in which flags a certain decimal variable `$decimal = 3660` is included. I´ve set up the flags with hexadecimal constants. After that the function "show_flags" should output every flag where the decimal variable "3660" is included.

I don´t have much experience with bit flags and tried it like that, but I dont get any output. This is the [demo](https://3v4l.org/7PEjP).

**Code**

```
$decimal= 3660;

const FLAG_1 = 0x1;
const FLAG_2 = 0x2; 
const FLAG_3 = 0x4;
const FLAG_4 = 0x8; 
const FLAG_5 = 0x10; 
const FLAG_6 = 0x20; 
const FLAG_7 = 0x40;
const FLAG_8 = 0x80; 
const FLAG_9 = 0x100; 
const FLAG_10 = 0x200; 
const FLAG_11 = 0x400;  
const FLAG_12 = 0x800;  

function show_flags ($decimal) {
  if ($decimal & FLAG_1) {
    echo "Flag 1 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_2) {
    echo "Flag 2 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_3) {
    echo "Flag 3 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_4) {
    echo "Flag 4 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_5) {
    echo "Flag 5 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_6) {
    echo "Flag 6 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_7) {
    echo "Flag 7 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_8) {
    echo "Flag 8 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_9) {
    echo "Flag 9 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_10) {
    echo "Flag 10 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_11) {
    echo "Flag 11 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_12) {
    echo "Flag 12 included.<br>\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to call the function. Read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not used, that is the reason why you do not see any result.

Calling it with

```
show_flags($decimal);
```

shows results as expected.

```
Flag 3 included.<br>
Flag 4 included.<br>
Flag 7 included.<br>
Flag 10 included.<br>
Flag 11 included.<br>
Flag 12 included.<br>
```